# Which is better to use for effects in general ? Jquery or CSS3 (Transitions)?

Tags: jquery, css, browser, compatibility, transition

I've been studying jQuery for a while now, and just lately I came across CSS3. I've noticed that most of the effects that jQuery can do, can also be done by CSS3 (Transitions).

However, I've read on some articles and have also noticed that CSS3 has some problems with browser compatibility. Also, making it more compatible means adding more code for each browser.

On the other hand, jQuery has an issue of not working at all when users have Javascript disabled on their browsers.

I'm having trouble weighing the pro's and con's here. I guess my lack of experience could be the cause. But if it's not too much to ask, which do you prefer to use to achieve animation? Which is easier to use? Are there other pro's and con's I'm not aware of?

Comment: I heard you like animations bro, so I put some CSS3 Animations in my jQuery Animations, so you can animate while you're animating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My rule of thumb is that if you can easily and efficiently do something in CSS3, then you should.  If what you're looking for can't be done that way, then resort to jQuery.

The most important thing though: **always** offer a fallback solution.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion,
I prefer use jquery.
There is a problem with cross-browser.

In jquery 1.8 release note, when developer set css3 property, the prefix like -moz, -webkit will be added.

Comment: That's great news ! Thank you ! I've just read the new release note.

but still , wouldn't that be useless for browsers that has javascript disabled ?

Comment: well....each method has Pros and cons. Maybe in your case, javascript disabled is a big issue.

Comment: But I guess Browser compatibility would be a much bigger issue for now. I think I'll go with jquery as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A good solution is to use jQuery but still make sure that your css will work if the user has JavaScript switched off. In my current role we are always finding cases where we can't use CSS3 features because of browser compatibility issues, especially with older versions of Internet Explorer.

Did you have some specific examples of features you are trying to compare between jQuery and CSS3?

Comment: Not at the moment , as I'm still getting to know CSS3 more. I'm just concerned on which I should be using for animations/effects. Jquery or CSS3 Transitions.

Comment: Ah ok cool. CSS3 has some pretty awesome transition animations, it will be great when browser support becomes more wide-spread and it can be used more safely in our projects. I'm very much looking forward to some older browsers being retired but I can't see it happening any time soon unfortunately.